# SendInput() function doesn't work inside game (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, artificial-intelligence, sendinput

I wrote an AI in C++ to try to play a game (Puyo Puyo Tetris), and to do this, I try to use SendInput() to simulate keyboard inputs to control the game, but for some reason, the inputs don't do anything. I know that the inputs themselves work because they work outside in notepad and browsers, etc. I suspect that that this may be part of the game's anticheat stopping the SendInput() function from going through inside the game.

Here's my code:

```
INPUT input = {0};

input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;

input.ki.wVk = VkKeyScanA('a');

SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));

Sleep(100);

ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(input));

input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;

Sleep(5);
```

Does anyone know how to get past this issue? Is there an alternative to SendInput() I can use? Thank you!

Comment: You need to eliminate __User Interface Privilege Isolation__  (UIPI) as a cause of your problems. see also _"...This function [SendInput] fails when it is blocked by UIPI. Note that neither GetLastError nor the return value will indicate the failure was caused by UIPI blocking...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput

Comment: Hmm, is there a way to bypass that?

Comment: I have no idea and it may not even be the real cause of the issue.

Comment: That's not how you use SendInput. Never send 1 in the first parameter. Batch them up in an array. Probably however the game doesn't want cheats. There are thousands of posts on this topic here. Search for them.

Comment: `SendInput` is meant to be used by assistive technology, things like on-screen keyboards, voice control software, etc. Its implementation is optimized for that use case, delivering input receivers as much information as required. That information includes the fact, that the input was generated. It's trivially easy for clients to filter out injected input, allowing games to protect themselves against naïve attempts at cheating. If you intend to become a better cheater, you're going to have to put in ***a lot*** more research effort.

Answer (score 1):

The sample you used `SendInput` is incorrect.

First, you only sent the keydown input once, and then when you clear the input(`ZeroMemory`), you also clear the `type` and `ki.wVk`. And you didn't even call `SendInput` for `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP`.

You only need to put keydown/up in one `SendInput`:

```
INPUT input[2] = { 0 };

input[0].type = input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input[0].ki.wVk = input[1].ki.wVk = VkKeyScanA('a');

input[1].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

In addition, *This function is subject to UIPI. Applications are permitted to inject input only into applications that are at an equal or lesser integrity level.* For this case, You'll need to [set UIAccess in the Application Manifest File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-securityoverview#setting-uiaccess-in-the-application-manifest-file).